# In Google Sheets, how to output/reference the value of the last bottom cell within a month period

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a table. Column A I have dates where each row is one day. I want to be able to reference / output the value of the last cell of a time period, in this case a month. How can I do that using formulas? I was trying to use this one below but for some reason is not working for other previous months, just the last:

```
=INDEX( FILTER( History!Q2500:Q , month(History!A2500:A)=month(C25&1) ) , ROWS( FILTER( History!Q2500:Q , NOT( ISBLANK( History!Q2500:Q ) ) ) ) )
```

In this case C25 is referencing "JUL" for July. But if I use C24 for "JUN" it no longer works. Any workaround for this?

Also in the future I'll need to also filter by year as well.
So in the sheet below I have this code:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(HISTORY!B:B, month(HISTORY!A:A)=month(B4&1), year(HISTORY!A:A)=year($B$2&1)),MATCH(143^143,HISTORY!$B:B))
```

And in this case it's not working at all.

EDIT:
Here's the view link for an example of what I want to do:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vppBGMcRWfevXoJXJhzx4_b1i_mB2wkxnyiHD_ySFBk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hey it's here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vppBGMcRWfevXoJXJhzx4_b1i_mB2wkxnyiHD_ySFBk/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks!

Comment: so you want balance per each month on the last date of the month? or sum of all days in each month?

Comment: Yes the last value entered for the month not the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(HISTORY!B2:B999, ISTEXT(HISTORY!A3:A1000))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B10&TO_TEXT(B12:B23), 
 SORTN(TEXT(SORT({HISTORY!A3:B, ROW(HISTORY!A3:A)}, 1, ), 
 {"yyyymmm", "#.00", "#"}), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Great. What if I want to include the last month of July?

Comment: That's great! Just one weird thing is I can't seem to make those values a custom number with $ or €. Why is that?

Comment: @verminous if answer helped you and solved your issue, please accept it by checking the mark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDBGo.png